# Remove whitespace from beginning of each array element

Tags: php, arrays, file

I have text file like below(note the whitespaces at the start):

```
  aaaaaaaaaa
  abbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbb
 ccccccccccccc ccccccccccc cccccccccc
ddddddddddd ddd dddddd ddddd
eeeeeeeeeee
```

How can I remove all whitespaces from beginning of each line?

Expected output:

```
aaaaaaaaaa
abbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbb
ccccccccccccc ccccccccccc cccccccccc
ddddddddddd ddd dddddd ddddd
eeeeeeeeeee
```

I tried to use `ltrim()`, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
$liness = file('file.txt');
$lines = ltrim($liness);

file_put_contents('file.txt', implode($lines));
echo $lines;
```

Comment: Just try `$lines = trim($liness);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok to `ltrim()`, but use it with `array_map()`:

```
$lines = array_map( 'ltrim', $liness );
file_put_contents( 'file.txt', implode($lines) );
```

And, don't use `echo` for an array, use `print_r()` instead. Or:

```
foreach( $lines as $line ) echo "$line\n";
```

---

- Read more about [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

Comment: Nice answer, especially with the array map!

Answer (score 1):

Read file into array, trim each arrays element and put together into a string, put that string back into file:

```
$lines = file('file.txt')
$lines = array_map('ltrim', $lines);
$str = implode($lines);
file_put_contents('file.txt',$str);
//echo nl2br($str) - to see your new file string
//print_r($lines) - to see file lines as array
```

Use PHPs **trim** functions.

```
trim(' a d  d d ');
//result: 'a d  d d', beginning and ending whitespaces removed
```

There is also `ltrim()`, and `rtrim()` functions to remove left and right spaces only.

Comment: Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in line 4

Warning: implode(): Argument must be an array in line 6

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php):

```
$lines = trim($liness);
```

[**From PHP Manual:**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)

trim — Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning and end of a string

Comment: Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in line 4

Warning: implode(): Argument must be an array in line 6

Comment: @vallez u need to use trim() after implode() function

Answer (score 0):

You need to read file line by line to trim.

```
<?php
$file = fopen('yourfile', "r");
$new_file="";
if($file){
    while (($line = fgets($file)) !== false) { // read file one line at a time.
        $newfile .= ltrim($line); // trim it! trim it! :)
    }
    fclose($file);
    echo $newfile; // !Adios
} else die('Unable to redy the file. :(');
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://ideone.com/vqPioD) for you

Other way to read the file in dom and use Reg-ex to fine "  .." find multiple space and replace with only one.